# Interrupt on ESP32 does not interrupt the main sometimes

Tags: timer, interrupt, esp32

On a ESP32 I want a piece of code to execute every 5ms, no matter what. For that i am using the high resolution timer apis of the esp-idf and configure the timer like this:

```
const esp_timer_create_args_t HPLTimer_args = {
  .callback = &timer_callback,
  .name = "HPLTimer",
  .dispatch_method = ESP_TIMER_ISR,
  .skip_unhandled_events = true};
esp_timer_handle_t timer_handler;
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_timer_create(&HPLTimer_args, &timer_handler));
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_timer_start_periodic(timer_handler, 5000));      // 5ms
```

In the configurations I chose Interrupt Priority 3 and enabled the ISR Method for the Timer. By looking on the Run Time behaviour of the chip within Impulse, I can see that the interrupt in general gets executed every 5ms as it is ment to be. However, sometimes the main gets a longer time slot (>20ms) and doesn't get interrupted by the interrupt. But on the other hand sometimes it does get interrupted. This can be seen in the picture.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could happen here and how to solve this?

Comment: Some operations disable interrupts for their duration. 20 ms is pretty long, but if your code is waiting on some IO completion with interrupts disabled, that's going to wreak havoc on all timing. You need to have a good look at what your main is doing and where it's disabling interrupts. OT: what's the tool you're using for task monitoring?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the input! I'm gonna check on that. The tool i am using to record the data is SEGGER SystemView. The visualization of the task timeline however in my opinion is better in impulse from toem (via eclipse).